# VB.net minimize a form with specific size

Tags: vb.net, forms, minimize

Here is a sample form I want to minimize.

This is the original size of the form:

[image: original form size]

When it is minimized it should hide other parts of the form and only display a specific area and should look like this:

[image: minimized form]

I should be able to return back the form to its original state and vice versa.
Is this possible? I have only tried minimizing a form to the taskbar but I have not tried this approach and I wanted to know if this can be possible because I find this feature very handy.

Comment: I have not seen any source which is related to this. I just wanted to experiment about this.

Comment: Set the `Anchor` property of every form element to "bottom" or "bottom left" and then change the dimension of the form during runtime. Catch the click event on the minimize button and replace it with your own code.

Comment: How do I do that. Where do I start. I am new to this form control thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use two Panel controls, both with Dock = Top.  Then it just takes two lines of code to switch between the expanded and collapsed view:

```
    panel1.Visible = !panel1.Visible;
    this.ClientSize = new Size(this.ClientSize.Width, panel2.Bottom);
```